# Please Review these Requirements im abit lost

Tags: requirements, functional-dependencies

Hi im insure about functional and non functional requirements, are these correct ?

FUNCTIONAL:

Player Creates account.

Player Chooses Region.

Player Chooses Player type.

Player TypeA/Player Typeb Views Game statistics.

Player TypeA Views opponent List.

Player TypeA/Player Typeb Selects Target/Assassin From Job List.

Player TypeA/Player Typeb Views opponent Map.

Player TypeA views weapons.

Player TypeA equips weapon .

Player TypeA Shoots weapon; compute hit probability.

Combat opponents player is hit; opponent eliminated Player TypeA receives points.

Player TypeA/Player Typeb sends message.

Player Typeb views target history.

This program requires a gps connection is this a functional requirement ?

Non-Functional: ?????
what would they be based on my functional ones ?

I will seriously give everyone cookies if they can answer my Questions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functional Requirements describe the features, behavior, business rules and general functionality that the proposed system must support.

Non-functional requirements describe everything else.  The scalability, availability, security, communication between various components, performance.

That sort of thing.

As I read your list it's purely functional.